# Can't get "Live Delegated Authentication" to work

Tags: php, windows

I try to get the Live Delegated Authentication to work for the purpose of reading the email addresses.

I am doing this in PHP with the help of the `windowslivelogin` library. The problem is that I get an error.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, i registered my application on the Azure webpage and got the appid and the secret into the code. This is what i use to initialize the Live Library :

```
$o = new WindowsLiveLogin();
$o->setAppId('000000004801B670');
$o->setSecret('secret');
$o->setSecurityAlgorithm('wsignin1.0');
$o->setDebug(true);
$o->setPolicyUrl('http://www.google.com/aides.html');
$o->setReturnUrl("http://michaelp.dev.gamepoint.net/framework/mainsite/contactimporter/?service=live");
return $o;
```

Then I call

```
$this->LiveLibrary->getLoginUrl()
```

And after I Login in to Live, it posts 2 things back, `$_POST['stoken']` and `$_POST['action']`.

As soon as I call

```
$this->LiveLibrary->processLogin($_REQUEST);
```

It fails and gives back an error that the token is invalid.

I tried getting Consent straight away by making redirecting to

```
$this->LiveLibrary->getConsentUrl("Contacts.View");
```

But that gives an 3007 error and says that it cant share the information

According to MS this means the following :

```
3007    
Consent Service API failed in the <method name> method. The application verifier is invalid.     

The offer security level requires that a valid application verifier be passed with the request.
```

I am using the following URL, generated by the library

> https://consent.live.com/Delegation.aspx?ps=Contacts.Invite&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fmichaelp.dev.gamepoint.net%2Fframework%2Fmainsite%2Fcontactimporter%2F%3Fservice%3Dlive&pl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faides.html&app=appid%3D000000004801B670%26ts%3D1251722931%26sig%3DD2gkM%252F%252FwlRXXfS64NMrV%252Bkt50v6dAOcESblfRk7j%252FUE%253D

I don't understand most of the documentation Microsoft has on this thing, I think its really unclear and chaotic. Also the Sample I tried doesn't work. I get an error message, it can't validate/decode the token. Same I get when I try the `processLogin()`.

Thanks in Advance,

Michael